# Navigating through Javadocs

Tags: java, programming-languages, javadoc

I am new to Java and as a first I read through a couple of books that deal with the Java language.

I had a couple of questions about the java docs. How does one 'navigate' them? Is it possible to learn new concepts using solely Javadocs?

Here's an example - I want to use nio to build an 'event' based lock-free chat server. For that I started looking through the J2SE 6 Java API docs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

I saw there were several packages that deal with nio - java.nio, java.nio.channels, java.nio.channels.spi, java.nio.charset, java.nio.charset.spi

I looked over the classes, interfaces etc. But I didn't actually know how to start using the 'nio' concepts. What documentation does one use to learn such concepts effectively?

Apologies if my question is a bit long winded or too conceptual. I am trying to figure out my way around the Java eco-system to find the best way to self-learn concepts effectively.

Thanks!

Comment: Refer the [Rox Java NIO tutorial](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/index.html). The API docs help once you know how the classes fall into place.

Comment: Only a few classes have some extra explanation about how to use them. For the others - or even in all cases - you're better of with going through the java tutorials you can find spread around the web or in books.

Answer (score 3):

An API documentation is for lookup of classes and methods. It's rarely useful for learning concepts. Use tutorials (or books) for that, e.g. the one from [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).

Comment: Thanks. Aren't there examples, developer guides for the features present in the Java language released by Sun/Oracle or do we have to always rely on 3rd parties to publish examples? Where do the authors of these publications get information about different design patterns / usages?

Comment: I don't understand. The tutorial I linked is from Oracle. In any case where it comes from doesn't really matter as long as it's correct and helpful. I just wanted to point out that the API documentation is a mere reference and not suited well for grasping a concept.

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started,

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-nio/

It's a kick start for NIO and has links to resources such as example applications

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Javadocs basically are used/written to explain the API one has written. I will not suggest them if you want to learn java. But if you want to learn someone's API, then that is the thing. Javadovs also help to understand the class hierarchies and dependancies.